# How to generate XML files of various list present in sharepoint?

Tags: list, xml

I want to generate XML files of the lists present inside a sharepoint site. The XML file will contain all the data and folders in a structured way. Is there any tool available to do this?

Has anybody worked on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, if you save the site as a template and include data, the resulting WSP/STP consists of a CAB file with XML data inside, making it machine-readable. I assume that's why you want the XML output? So you can parse it in code?

Answer (score 1):

Try using content deployment wizard available here: http://spdeploymentwizard.codeplex.com/

Once your lists are exported in .cmp file, you can rename it to .cab and open he cab file and access bunch of XML files.

Answer (score -1):

Save the list as template and use it as your wish. it will be generated like XML.